# How to calculate sum of cells from chosen column which meets chosen conditions

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel table which contains 10 columns with object parameter values, every column has a label in the first row with a parameter name, and in the 11th column I have indicated the class to which the object belongs.
I am trying to make a formula which can calculate the sum of parameter values for an object given a parameter name and class name.
I need to chose a parameter name in a list field and class name in a list field and get the sum.

Comment: How do you plan on selecting the parameter/class? Having the user type it into a cell?  I think this is attainable using formulas, but is probably more tractable using VBA.

Comment: I use a cell with drop down list on worksheet

Answer (score 1):

Create the two ListBoxes and then create a Linked Cell for each of them, the following formula uses N1 for the parameter Linked Cell, and O1 for the class Linked Cell.

```
=SUMIF(K:K, O1, INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1, MATCH(N1, A1:J1, 0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% clear on the question, so I asume the following

- a table with 11 column headings A1..K1
- column headers A1..J1 are parameter names ("P1".."P10")
- column header K1 is "Class Name"
- multiple rows containing numeric entries in columns A..J and text entries in column K

The easiest would be to place an Autofilter on the header row and create a SUBTOTAL(109, ...) for sum or SUBTOTAL(102, ...) for count below the list for each parameter. Then filter the class and look up the total sum/count for each parameter.

An alternative would be to create a pivot table with P1 .. P10 in the data area (count or sum) and class as a page field .... then again you may select a distinct class and parameter to narrate the results

Finally, you can use the DSUM(), DCOUNT() or DCOUNTA() functions with

- your table range (including headers!) as the database range
- a field N2 with a list validation based on A1..J1 as field parameter (this is to select your parameter)
- a range M1..M2 as the criteria parameter

  - M1 containing string "Class Name" (same as K1)
  - M2 containing the class name you want to look up - if you want a drop down list for this as well, you must have all class names in a seperate range, you cannot use column K for this as class names will not be unique there, but you can use the same validation for column K and the criteria

Hope that helps - good luck MikeD